# Is there an option to let DSolve output exponential functions in preference to trigonometric functions as default results?

Tags: differential-equations, output-formatting

For example,

```
DSolve[y''[x] + y[x] == 0, y[x], x]
```

gives

```
{{y[x] -> C[1] Cos[x] + C[2] Sin[x]}}
```

as the result.

Can we add any option(s) to make us get

```
{{y[x] -> C[1] E^(I x) + C[2] E^(-I x)}}
```

instead?

Maybe `TrigToExp` would be suggested, but it will lead to extra 1/2 factor in the solutions.

Update1: Admittedly, combination of `TrigToExp` and `GeneratedParameters -> (2 C[#] &)` can realize the expected output. However, I actually want a pure option of `DSolve` that can do the job.

So, there is none of such an option? And does this state of affairs mean that MMA regards trigonometric functions as more fundamental than exponential functions?

Comment: The arbitrary constants are arbitrary so you can change them at will.  `(DSolve[y''[x] + y[x] == 0, y[x], x][[1]] //
   TrigToExp) /. {C[1] :>
    2 C[1], C[2] :> 2 C[2]}`

Comment: @BobHanlon So we can use GeneratedParameters -> (2 C[#] &) as the option together with the use of TrigToExp?

Comment: Yes you can use the revised expressions. When you add initial conditions the arbitrary constants will resolve to satisfy the initial conditions whatever the form of the arbitrary constants.

Comment: `eqn = y''[x] + y[x] == 0;  soln = DSolve[eqn, y, x,
     GeneratedParameters -> (2 C[#] &)][[1]] // TrigToExp;  eqn /. soln` evaluates to `True`

Comment: @BobHanlon I believe you have an unmatched square bracket.

Comment: @BobHanlon Sorry, you are right. The typo was mine.